# When in swift 3.0 nil coalescing used, didn't get expected result

Tags: swift3, null-coalescing-operator

Implemented below code where, if my dictionary doesn't have key "key1" then value1 should be initialized with blank dictionary [:], code executes but never comes into if-let block.

Suggest correct solution, in case i have used nil coalescing in a wrong way

```
if let value1 = ((dataDict["key1"] as? Dictionary<String,Any>?) ?? [:]){
print(value1) 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `if - let` in conjunction with the nil coalescing operator

```
let value1 : Dictionary<String,Any> = dataDict["key1"] as? Dictionary<String,Any> ?? [:]
print(value1)
```

or shorter

```
let value1 = dataDict["key1"] as? [String:Any] ?? [String:Any]()
```

Comment: Or even shorter: `let value1 = dataDict["key1"] as? [String:Any] ?? [:]`

Comment: @vadian, Could you please explain why can't we use both if-let and nil coalescing together, as in my implementation if i know that this "dataDict["key1"]" has the possibilities to be nil then in if-let statement itself i would like to assign blank dictionary. And there its not working

Comment: Actually the nil coalescing operator does an `if - let`. If the key `key1` does not exist or the value is not `[String:Any]` the empty (non-optional) dictionary will be assigned to the variable otherwise the unwrapped(!) value.